# Is there a way to to use iWeb 09 to integrate with facebook?

Tags: facebook, html, integration, html4

I am setting up a website in iWeb. I inserted an HTML box and copied the code but nothing showed up. Youtube videos work find. I think it might be because iWeb doesn't support HTML 5. Is there any way that I can get HTML 4 versions of code from facebook? Or even some way to convert HTML 5 to HTML 4? Thanks!

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if anyone here uses iWeb. Voted to be moved to superuser.com -> I would expect you'll find it easier to get an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

On the social plugins, when you click [get code], the popup has three tabs at the top.  One for HTML5, one for XFBML and one for IFRAME code.  Try one of the others.